# Kotlin multiplatform test error ("Error_0: Fail to fetch")

Tags: kotlin, testing, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kotlin-multiplatform project that has a kotlinJS client and a JVM backend. I'm creating some integration tests that are supposed to test the API calls from the client. The function is a suspend function with an HttpClient call with a POST method. I'm using kotlinx-coroutines-test, the test looks like this:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Test
fun testGetSingleResult() = runTest {
   val result = getSingleResult(TESTED_ID)
   assertThat(result.ID).isEqualTo(TESTED_ID)
}
```

It should call the server in localhost:8080 and receive the result with the given ID. Instead of that, it gives the following error:

```
Error_0: Fail to fetch
Error_0: Fail to fetch
    at <global>.<unknown>(/tmp/_karma_webpack_59097/commons.js:148488)
...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jsBrowserTest'.
```

I don't know what's happening, I thought that maybe the test is not launching the backend, so it won't find it when doing the request but I tried running the app at the same time that I launched the test and nothing changed.

EDIT:
[Here](https://github.com/IAAA-Lab/space-ql/blob/main/build.gradle.kts) is my build.gradle file and the link to the project.

Comment: How are you configuring the JS and JVM build? Can you share your `build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: I just added a link to the gradle file at the end of the entry! @aSemy

Comment: Please, file an issue https://kotl.in/issue.